# Creating numeric up down or value control using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc4 razor, and I would like to know if there is some control in razor to allow enter numeric and positive integers values. Is there any?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the same in MVC by using the htmlAttributes parameter of HtmlHelper's EditorFor():

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreditCardExpirationMonth, new { htmlAttributes = new { type="number", min="1", max="12", @class = "form-control" } })
```

Answer (score 2):

The only "built in" thing you can do is use HTML5 input in your form:

```
<input type="number" min="0" />
```

Or

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

For the list of all input type number attributes check out this link
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: I am not interested in using HTML5.

Comment: Than you have to build your own using jquery for example.

Answer (score 1):

I built my own using jquery

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "txtUpDown" })
<label class="lblUp">+</label>
<label class="lblDown">-</label>
```

then in your script

```
$('.lblUp').keyup(function(){
    $('.txtUpDown').val() = (+$('.txtUpDown').val() + 1);
});
$('.lblDown').keyup(function(){
    if($('.txtUpDown').val() > 0){
        $('.txtUpDown').val() = (+$('.txtUpDown').val() - 1);
    }
});
```